# resemblejs "npm run test" tests not passing, can't extend timeout

Tags: node.js, package.json, resemblejs

I have cloned the repo for the resemble.js project code (https://github.com/rsmbl/Resemble.js#readme) and have been attempting to test the software by using the "npm run test" command. The test suites fail and it does not accept "jest.setTimeout(20000)" as a command to adjust the tests. I think I may be missing some packages but I don't know what they are.

[Test results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4JTo.png)

Any input would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Please Go To That Folder where you have cloned the repo
And Run a Command called :

`npm i` or just `npm install`

This should fix it !

:)

Have a great day / night ahead !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).